# Trying to activate GeoRover LocusTracker toolbar; another way to import to shapefile?

Tags: convert, excel

In ArcGIS I'm trying to activate the GeoRover LocusTracker toolbar but it won't come off its grayed out status. Might anyone know how to make it active?

If anyone knows of another way to import an Excel file or convert an Excel file into a shapefile (with just fields of FID numbers, province names, and MGRS).